# Unique cliques in list in (Python)

Tags: python, list, unique

I have list with lists:

```
cliques = [ [1,9,5], [3,5,4], [10,7,0], [2,7,5], [6,11], [6,5,4], [3,1], [11, 0]]
```

I select one item from the list randomly:

```
rand_clique = numpy.random.choice(cliques)
```

For example `cliques[2] = [10,7,0]`
And I want to create a new list with unique values inside the `Cliques` elements.
As a result, I get a list:

```
unique_cliques = [[10,7,0], [1,9,5], [6,11]]
```

I wrote the code, but I think it can be optimized better, how can I do this?

```
import numpy as np

unique_cliques = []
not_unique_cliques = []

cliques = [[1, 9, 5], [3, 5, 4], [10, 7, 0], [2, 7, 5], [6, 11], [6, 5, 4], [3, 1], [11, 0]]
rand_clique = np.random.choice(cliques)
unique_cliques.append(rand_clique)

for elem in rand_clique:
    not_unique_cliques.append(elem)

for clique in cliques:
    temp = []
    count = 0
    for elem in clique:
        if elem not in not_unique_cliques:
            count += 1
            temp.append(elem)
    if count == len(clique):
        unique_cliques.append(clique)
        not_unique_cliques = not_unique_cliques + temp

print(rand_clique)
print(unique_cliques)
```

It would be nice if the program could take elements not in order, but each time a random element satisfying the condition above.

Comment: Not sure how to optimize your approach, but you could make it random by calling `random.shuffle(cliques)` before doing any processing

Comment: Are you using numpy just for that?  There is stdlib `random.choice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the list out of a shuffled version of the cliques list by filtering on seen values:

```
import random
cliques = [[1, 9, 5], [3, 5, 4], [10, 7, 0], [2, 7, 5], [6, 11], [6, 5, 4], [3, 1], [11, 0]]

unique_cliques = []
seen = set()
for clique in random.sample(cliques,len(cliques)):
    if seen.intersection(clique): continue
    seen.update(clique)
    unique_cliques.append(clique)

print(unique_cliques) # your results will vary

# [[6, 11], [3, 5, 4], [10, 7, 0]]
```

*this will randomize not only the first sublist but subsequent ones as well*

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best :

```
import numpy as np

unique_cliques = []
not_unique_cliques = []

cliques = [[1, 9, 5], [3, 5, 4], [10, 7, 0], [2, 7, 5], [6, 11], [6, 5, 4], [3, 1], [11, 0]]
rand_clique = np.random.choice(cliques)
unique_cliques.append(rand_clique)
not_unique_cliques.extend(rand_clique)

for clique in cliques:
    if len(set(clique)&set(not_unique_cliques))==0:
        unique_cliques.append(clique)
        not_unique_cliques.extend(clique)


print(rand_clique)
print(unique_cliques)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sets should improve efficiency:

```
import random
cliques = [[1, 9, 5], [3, 5, 4], [10, 7, 0], [2, 7, 5], [6, 11], [6, 5, 4], [3, 1], [11, 0]]
rand_clique = random.choice(cliques)
unique_cliques = [rand_clique]
nonunique_elements = set(rand_clique)
for clique in cliques:
   if not set(clique).intersection(nonunique_elements):
       unique_cliques.append(clique)
       nonunique_elements.update(clique)
print(unique_cliques)
```

BTW, note that the result differs depending on which clique has been selected by `random.choice`!